# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

Tags: java, hibernate

I work with hibernate and I have this java method :

```
 public Integer getNumber(String user) {
            SQLProperties properties = new SQLProperties();



            String query = "select out_count('"+user+"')";
            query += SQLUtils.getProperties(properties);


            SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
            sqlQuery = SQLUtils.addScalar(sqlQuery, properties);

            List<Integer> list = sqlQuery.list();

                 System.out.println("val : "+list.get(0));
            return list.get(0);
        }
```

but when I test I have this error :

```
val : 200
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
    at com..hibernate.model.dao.testDAO.getNumber(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the actual type that's being returned.  You're getting a String out of that query.  Convert it to an Integer with `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a `List<String>`, not a `List<Integer>`. There's probably an unchecked warning showing up, isn't there?